# Best way to set IEnumerator to end

Tags: c#, performance

I have custom class that implement `IEnumerable<int[]>` interface and save current `Enumerator`. When added new element I need set enumerator to last element.

Sample code for set enumerator to end:

```
IEnumerable<int> seq = ...
seq.Reset();
for (int i = 0; i < seq.Count; i++)
{
  seq.MoveNext();    
}
```

How do this faster?
(Can I go to the end can't not scroll all sequence elements?)

Comment: Do _what_ faster than _what_?

Comment: faster (in performance)? that is the only way. Reset, MoveNext are the only operation available for iteration ( when using IEnumerable/IEnumerator)

Comment: Do you have a **Count** property in **IEnumerable**? :-O

Comment: @Famos it's a method, not a property! ;) (and it'll be invoked for each iteration of the loop, iterating through the enumeration again and again)

Comment: Why are you not using an array for this?

Comment: The IEnumerable interface is not intended to point to the last element of the sequence (and it'll surprise its users), let who will use your code to get a _normal_ IEnumerable and to call Last() if it's what they want.

Comment: This behavior won't make any sense to anyone using your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if faster means less code (another alternative is),

```
        IEnumerable<int> seq = ...

        while (seq.MoveNext())
        {
           var item = seq.Current;
        }
```

**EDIT**
you want [seq.Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx)
It is an extension method and has code similar to above.

**EDIT2**

> > i need seq.Current=seq.Last();

your code is similar to

```
        IEnumerable<int> seq = ...
        int count=0;
        //Following while is equivalent to seq.Count
        while (seq.MoveNext()) 
        {
           count++;
        }
        int i=0;
        while (i<count)
        {
          seq.MoveNext();
        }
```

Using IEnumerator only it is not possible to set seq.Current to Last in one iteration as you never know where to stop.

Comment: i need seq.Current=seq.Last();

Comment: using IEnumerator, it is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

The `for` statement will iterate from `x` to `y`, with a pre-defined increment, like so:

```
for (`start`; `until`; `increment`)
```

e.g. If we wanted to loop from 0 to 9, with an increment of 1, we would write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

If you have an object that implements a `next` type method, you may want to use a `while` loop.

```
while (seq.CurrentItem != null)
{
    // do something with the current item and move to next
    seq.Next();
}
```

I would recommend reading up about [loops in C#](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson04).